# installing Ubuntu 12.04 failing

Tags: 12.04, installation

I am frustrated.  I can't get Ubuntu Installed.

I wrote the .ISO file into a DVD and booted from it.  I choose wubi.exe file.  I selected Demo Install but the system reboots quickly without copying any files, then it restarted, and booted from CD.

I have 3 Choices.  Installing Ubuntu along side windows ,replace windows with Ubuntu, and something else.
When I choose Installing Ubuntu along side windows, my PC restarts and does not do anything.  When I choose something else, I see a page for installing Ubuntu in a partition.  I choose a partition ,and change the format of this partition to Linux partition and format it to start installing Ubuntu.

when the installing complete I restart PC,the Ubuntu added to my OS list but when I choose it I see error like this: please insert win7 CD and repair the driver,

file :/ubuntu/winboot/wabilder

status ; 0x00000f

Info : the selected entry could not be load because the application missing or corrupt

where is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried booting from the Windows 7 CD, and did a repair?

Comment: no , no I didn't tried! I do now.

Comment: Hi, here is a guide to do a step by step instructions to install ubuntu 12.04 : http://news.softpedia.com/news/Installing-Ubuntu-12-04-LTS-266201.shtml

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to use WUBI then you just run it from inside Windows

visit this link from Internet Explorer etc and start the install from in windows

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

Comment: is there different between WUBI that you liked and WUBU in .iso file?